# How to wake up Device using PowerManager.wakeUp in Android API 8

Tags: android

I want to wake up Device by using

```
powerManager.wakeUp(SystemClock.uptimeMillis())
```

according to [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#wakeUp%28long%29). But since it was added in API level 17, how can i get the same approach on API level 8.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using activity as below :

To wake up device, start an activity (i'm calling from service) as below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

On activity's onCreate() Lifecycle step :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        /* Add before setContentView(...) */
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wake_up_helper);           
    }
```

Now device is waked up from sleeping and activity is running on foreground.